# How do I Generate a Bearer Token for cURL to Get Thru IAP (GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, json, service-accounts, oauth, google-cloud-identity

I need to cURL a web app hosted behind IAP on GCP.

Normally, users log in through IAP and use the web app, but I need to run some cURL commands (interactive and non-interactive) that hit the web app URLs (for example:     `https://myapp.com/get_pics/1)`

I cannot figure out how to get a Bearer token from GCP that I can use in the authorization header for cURL.

I can set up a service account with "IAP Secured Web App User" role and I have the JSON key for this service account, but I am not sure where to go after that to get a proper Bearer token that IAP will accept.

Comment: I think that this information about [genarate the authentication](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/programmatic-oauth-clients#service_accounts_and_gcloud) can be useful.

Comment: @NadiaEspinosa - Your link is for creating an Access Token. In this question, an Identity Token is required.

Comment: In your case, you need an OIDC Identity Token. Is the identity a user or service account? While developing use the CLI to generate this token: **gcloud auth print-identity-token** https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-identity-token Also specify the services that you are using. There is a parameter for **aud** (--audiences) which is the URL for the service. Tip: use Python instead of Curl. You will have a much easier time creating OAuth/OIDC tokens.

Comment: The identity is a service account. The token is for an iOS client hitting a REST API behind IAP. Short lived tokens are a bummer since it's just testing against an IAP protected API. Python isn't much help. It's a use case GCP hasn't considered. The developer is third party so we're not giving gcloud to them ergo the service account idea.

Comment: @sts Since this case has been open for 3 months now, I would like to know if you found a way to solve your issue.

Comment: Nope. We punted.

Answer (score 2):

For IAP you need to provide a OIDC identity token. You can use `gcloud` to create it for you, or use any other mean as described in [Programmatic authentication](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account).

I assume you have gcloud, so I'll show you how to use that:

1. Login using the service account

```sh
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file service-account-key.json
```

2. Send your request

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token --audiences="xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com")" https://myapp.com/get_pics/1
```

> Make sure that you granted the service account the `iap.httpsResourceAccessor`-permission, or you'll still be denied.

- Bonus: Don't use service account key files. Impersonate a service account from your current user profile.

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token --include-email --audiences="xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com" --impersonate-service-account=service_account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com)" https://myapp.com/get_pics/1
```

Comment: Belated thanks. Just got back to this. Yes, we use gcloud. We'll give this a try...

Comment: Follow up. This worked great. Note that if you want to hit Firebase with curl, the service account needs Role: Cloud Datastore User. Google doesn't document this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**I cannot figure out how to get a Bearer token from GCP that I can use in the authorization header for cURL.**

According with the [Google Public Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_proxy-authorization_header)

> If your application occupies the Authorization request header, you can
> include the ID token in a Proxy-Authorization: Bearer header instead.
> If a valid ID token is found in a Proxy-Authorization header, IAP
> authorizes the request with it. After authorizing the request, IAP
> passes the Authorization header to your application without processing
> the content.
>
> If no valid ID token is found in the Proxy-Authorization header, IAP
> continues to process the Authorization header and strips the
> Proxy-Authorization header before passing the request to your
> application.

**Bearer Token OIDC**

This document also includes code samples to:

- [Obtain an OIDC token for the default service account](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#obtaining_an_oidc_token_for_the_default_service_account),
- [Obtaining an OIDC token from a local service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#obtaining_an_oidc_token_from_a_local_service_account_key_file)
- [Obtaining an OIDC token in all other cases.](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#obtaining_an_oidc_token_in_all_other_cases)

And in this link you can find more information about [Verify Bearer Token](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/verifying-bearer-tokens) in GCP

**Bearer Token Auth**

After some research I found two pages that describe How to provide your service account authentication as a Bearer token and How to send Curl POST request with Bearer Token Authorization Header.

The first one is part of the [Google Developers public documentation](https://developers.google.com/spectrum-access-system/guides/authorization-and-authentication?hl=en), and describes the process to **obtain a Bearer token with your service account.**

> 1. [Install the gcloud command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install).
> 2. Authenticate to your service account. In the following command,
>    replace `${KEY_FILE}` with the path to your service account key
>    file:
>
>    ```
>    gcloud auth activate-service-account
>    --key-file ${KEY_FILE}
>    ```
> 3. Use your service account to obtain an authorization token:
>
>    ```
>    gcloud auth print-access-token
>    ```
>
>    The command returns an access token value.
>
> When you use the API, pass the token value as a Bearer token in an
> Authorization header. See the following example:
>
> ```
>     curl -X GET -H "X-Goog-User-Project: ${CLIENT_PROJECT}" \  
>     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \  
>     -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \ 
> "https://sasportal.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/customers"
> ```
>
> Set `${CLIENT_PROJECT}` to the [ID of the Google Cloud Project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects) from
> which you make the requests, and then set `${TOKEN}` to the
> authorization token.

And in [this link](https://reqbin.com/req/c-hlt4gkzd/curl-bearer-token-authorization-header-example) you will find information and examples about **Curl Request With Bearer Token Authorization Header**

Comment: There are two types of tokens: OAuth Access Token and OIDC Identity Tokens. The question is about IAP (Identity Aware Proxy), your answer is for a different service. IAP requires an OIDC Identity Token.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i already edited my answer.